# What did Ptolemy mean when he

Tags: geography

What did Ptolemy mean when he said that

> Geography is the wonderful science of seeing the glimpse of earth in heaven.

Does it have to do with the differences in celestial bodies when seen from different areas of the earth?

Comment: I am having trouble identifying where Ptolemy wrote this. Adding a proper citation would be helpful, in particular to assess the quality of the translation from classical Greek.

Comment: The most likely place where Ptolemy might have written this is in his *Geography*. Since I cannot read classical Greek, I have been perusing an Italian translation for the past half hour, but so far have been unable to identify any language that resembles the supposed quote. Are we sure this isn't a made-up quote? From my participation in History of Math and Science Stackexchange I am aware that a large percentage of pithy sayings attributed to famous people are (1) invented from whole cloth (2) *vaguely* resemble something a person actually said or wrote (3) poor and misleading translations

Comment: @njuffa 95% of statistics are simply made up.

Comment: @Spencer Yes. The problem is demonstrating which ones are made up. I spent an additional two hours looking at an English translation of Ptolemy's *Geography* from the 1930s (widely considered to be very poor, though), a Latin translation of *Geography*, Latin translations of other books by Ptolemy, and collections of aphorisms and pithy saying in multiple languages. No indications that Ptolemy ever wrote what is quoted above or something similar.